# what does the .f in 1000.f mean? c++

Tags: c++

I am following a tutorial on how to make a game with SDL. At a certain point in the tutorial I need to calculate the game's FPS. The tutorial does the following:

```
caption << "Average Frames Per Second: " << frame / ( fps.get_ticks() / 1000.f );
```

Now, I know exactly what the code does, except for the part where it divides by 1000.f. I've been looking but just can't find what .f means.

So my question is, what does .f mean? And why is it there?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`1000` is an `int` literal.

`1000.` is a `double` literal.

`1000.f` is a `float` literal.

Comment: Why is it a double and a float at the same time? Why would they do that?

Answer (score 9):

It means this is a `float` constant rather than a `double` constant.  As for the effect, on most C++ compilers, it will have no effect as the `float` will be converted to a `double` to do the divide.

Answer (score 7):

`.f` makes the number `float` type.

Just see this interesting demonstration:

```
float a = 3.2;
if ( a == 3.2 )
    cout << "a is equal to 3.2"<<endl;
else
    cout << "a is not equal to 3.2"<<endl;

float b = 3.2f;
if ( b == 3.2f )
    cout << "b is equal to 3.2f"<<endl;
else
    cout << "b is not equal to 3.2f"<<endl;
```

Output:

> a is not equal to 3.2
>   b is equal to 3.2f

Do experiment here at ideone: http://www.ideone.com/WS1az

Try changing the type of the variable `a` from `float` to `double`, see the result again!

Comment: Isn't the `f` in the `b` assignment redundant?

Comment: @naught101: Yes. It is redundant practically. If you don't use it, then `3.2` which is `double` will convert to `float` anyway. BTW, that is not *assignment*; that is *initialization*.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I have no idea about C++. Presumably compilers would be smart enough to avoid the conversion, and you'd end up with the same compiled code, right?

Answer (score 5):

It is telling you the literal `1000.` should be treated as a `float`.  Look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/constants/) for details.

Answer (score 5):

It means 1000.f is treated as a float.

Answer (score 4):

A floating point literal can have a suffix of (f, F, l or L).  "f and F" specify a `float` constant and "l and L" a `double`.